# patch attributes in sql database

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a SQL database (MariaDB) that is regularly updated by a script copying data over from another database. Now, in the MariaDB there are few manual patches that need to be done, e.g. changing column X of row Y to a new value. Amount of patches are below 1% of the database.

Obviously, the script will overwrite again the patches but the patches need to be persistent. What would be a good design to keep the patches but continue the script that copies everything but ignores patches?

Idea 1: Create a "patch" table with columns "table_name", "primary_key", "column", "patched_value". Add each patch as a new row. Downside: Each read from the database now needs to further join with the patch table to find any patches that overrides

Idea 2: Add a new column "patched" in each table. If patched = 0 the script will copy the data over. If patched = 1 the script will ignore. Downside: If I only patch one field, it locks the patch to the entire row

Idea 3: Same as 2 but double all columns from "foo" with "foo_patched". Downside: Increases database by a lot and makes all queries more complex, given that only 1% will be patched.

Idea 4: Keep patches outside of DB, e.g. in a csv. And handle it at app side (currently PHP)

Other ideas?

Comment: So there are 2 databases, is one a _Master_ and one just the replica? But in the replica you want to allow some changes but those changes never sync back to the master, and those local changes shouldn't be overwritten in the next sync from master... Can you describe the business scenario around this more? This concept of _"patches"_ sounds very application logic specific and doesn't refer to schema changes but just some data value changes.

Comment: I think you're asking about ["schema migration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration), but it's unclear. Could you provide a concrete example of what you want done? Also why, this feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: No matter what solution you decide to go for, you have to store additional data and spend additional processing time on that. I would handle the patches centrally, not in the client datanase, so the correct data is pushed down.